# PHP HTML - how to get file upload full path in php process page

Tags: php, html

i am trying to get upload file full path from form to php process page

HTML PAGE

```
    <form id="form_837044" class="appnitro" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="watermark_image_example.php">

    <li id="li_3" >
    <label class="description" for="element_3">Upload a File </label>
    <div>
        <input id="element_3" name="pfilename" class="element file" type="file" value="hello"/> 
    </div>  
    </li>       

                <li class="buttons">
            <input type="hidden" name="pfilename1" value="pfilename" />

            <input id="saveForm" class="button_text" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

PHP PAGE

```
  $pfilename1=$_POST['pfilename'];
  echo $pfilename1;
```

thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File information is in `$_FILES` superglobal array and the temporary filename with path is in `$_FILES['pfilename']['tmp_name']`, so to just get the directory name from it:

```
echo dirname($_FILES['pfilename']['tmp_name']);
```

Or for the path and file:

```
echo $_FILES['pfilename']['tmp_name'];
```

Comment: getting following resuit...C:\Windows\Temp but my selected path is c:/newimages/houseimage.jpg thats what i want to get in php page.

Comment: You can't get the client path of the original file.  Not with PHP or JavaScript.

Comment: Why would you want that path anyway?